# 2D Array - C vs Java

Tags: java, c, arrays, programming-languages, multidimensional-array

What is the difference between a **Dynamic 2D Array** in C (int **arr) and A 2D Array in Java (int [][]arr) ?

Is a 2D Array in C/C++ similar to a 2D Array in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will change according to part you want to compare.

In Java, arrays are objects that have methods and attributes, however in C/C++ they are not objects.

Both of them similar in a way that array dimension can be different. I mean arr[0] can be 3-dimensional, arr[1] 5-dimensional, etc.

Java is checking array bounds therefore will throw exceptions if you try to reach an index outside of the array boundaries, however in C/C++ no exception will be thrown however, you might end up with an "segmentation fault".

Answer (score 0):

Very much similar.  Of course, arrays in Java are full-fledged objects instead of "bare" sequences of the constituent types, but multi-dimension arrays are done effectively the same way, with an array of pointers to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are quite similar. The benefit of the java arrays is that you cannot access a cell that doesn't exist (you get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException).

I think the important bit is that both are **references** to an array, so there's no duplication/cloning of the arrays when you pass them to a method.